# How to determine where something is stored in memory for layered structure

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm working on an assignment that concerns where things are located in memory, static, stack, or heap. I understand the basics, but am confused by questions such as the following:

A character that is stored in a C++ string object if the object is a local variable of a public member function of a class.

I'm confused by how I would go about determining where in memory such a character is stored. I expect an activation record for a function to be pushed to the stack, the string then is part of that activation record, and therefore the associated characters are also on the stack. Is this correct?

Is there a general way to approach this? Should I even be concerned with all the outer layers or is there a way to sufficiently deduce where something is stored in memory without concerning myself with all of the nuances of where it is stored in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. If you declare a `std::string` on the stack (as a local variable, say), then all of its *member variables* are located on the stack. Its member variables *likely* include a length field and a pointer to the character array. (This is up to the implementation of the standard library: the standard does not define exactly what private members a `std::string` must have.)

The characters themselves are not on the stack, though. `std::string` dynamically allocates its memory using `new`, so the character data is on the heap.

Comment: the same applies to `std::vector` and the rest of the `containers`

Comment: Can I say the same thing for members within a class declaration? For instance, `class Foo {int foo;};` would you expect `foo` to appear on the heap?

Comment: @mike No; again, when you declare an instance of a class on the stack, all of the member variables are located on the stack. It's just that in the case of `string` the character data itself is not stored in a member variable, it's stored in a dynamically allocated buffer, and a member variable holds a pointer to that buffer.

Comment: Related to how `std::string` stores the chars, there's also SSO (small/short string optimization) to take into account.

Comment: I guess that goes along with @Claudiordgz comment. Is the difference between allocating on the stack and heap (generally) `Object object;` vs `Object * object = new Object();`?

Comment: @mike Yes. Function arguments are also on the stack.

Comment: @mike yes, in the end everything will even boil down to c functions for memory management (even that `new`). You can't allocate something on the heap without using pointers. You are pointing to a remote location in memory.

Comment: The pointer itself though may or may not be on the stack, correct?

Comment: @mike Let's be careful about the terminology: the *pointer itself* is on the stack (assuming it's a member variable of an object that was declared on the stack). What the pointer points to may or may not be on the stack. If the pointer holds a value returned by `new` then what it points to is on the heap. If it holds a pointer to a local variable then what it points to is on a stack. If it's NULL or uninitialized then it doesn't point to anything.

Comment: My mistake, yes that makes sense, I was thinking of the `new` case